# How does 'Delivery Window' work?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm building a Journey with a data extension as the entry point. This DE gets refreshed/populated hourly. I'm setting up a Send Email, and on the Configure Delivery step, there is a Delivery Window checkbox. I'm wondering how this works? If I have this option checked, and I have a from time of 6am and a to time of 10pm, will records that join the journey at 11pm never receive an email, or will the system queue that email to be delivered the next day at 6am? Thanks for any help someone can offer on this matter.

Edit: here is a screenshot of what I am seeing...

[image: Screen shot of the Configure Delivery screen in Marketing Cloud]

And here is the text of the tooltip, which states "Send Throttle sends emails during the hours you specify every day, starting the day you send the email, until all of the emails are sent." The link goes [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_throttle.htm&type=5)

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing this option on my account. Which stack are you on?

Comment: Hello @EliotHarper, we're on stack 7.

Comment: Interesting. I would assume in that scenario that emails would be quarantined until 6am the following day, but I'd recommend testing it, to be certain. I don't have that feature on any of my accounts, but it would be easy enough for you to validate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so I went ahead and, based on a recommendation from @EliotHarper, decided to test this myself. Here are my findings.

So I have a Journey that has an API entry point. In the Data Extension that holds the records, I have a 'CampaignCompleted' column that defaults to `false`. The Journey has the following steps. After entry...

1. Wait 1 minute
2. Sends an email
3. Wait 1 minute
4. Update the 'CampaignCompleted' value to true
5. Wait 1 minute
6. Exit (on minute 3)

I went ahead and added a Delivery Window from 2pm to 3pm for the email that is sent at step 2. I triggered an API call to the entry point at 12:45pm, and saw that the record made its way successfully into the Journey, and the Data Extension. I checked the Journey after 3 minutes and saw that a record went through the entire Journey (For my test, it was the 6th entry)...

[image: Screenshot of test Journey]

So by 12:48pm, the record on the Data Extension had been changed to `true`.

After lunch, I checked my email and saw that an email delivered to me at 2pm. So essentially, the email gets queued to be sent during the Delivery Window, but the record within the Journey continues down its path. This was important for me to know, because I thought maybe the Delivery Window might prevent that from happening.

Anyway, I hope others might find this helpful, I'd also welcome any other tests someone can think of. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

just adding that you can turn on this feature in SET UP under Feature Settings > Email Studio > Email Optional Features

Comment: "Delivery Window" option doesn’t appear in the list of options in that menu, has this changed?

Comment: I *think* you turn on Send Throttling and then the Delivery Window is available when sending an email.